# problems with bulk editing in MVC 2 C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bulk

Im having issues when trying to post a IList back to the controller here is some of the code

My controller

`public ActionResult Approvals(ICollection<ApprovalListModel> model) {`

My pages 
`<%@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<IList<Book>>" %>`

`<% for (int i = 0; i < ViewData.Model.Count; i++) { %>` 


 `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Title) %>...`

But when it posts back it only ever returns the first item and missing data as well

Comment: Does MVC support selecting an index on the model like that? I thought you were only allowed individual named fields on a model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue i was incrementing i twice so the sequence was out of wack wen 0 2 4 6 8 so it would only bring back 0 :-S